# How is the default route configured in MPTCP?

Tags: routes, mptcp

I understand that packets are usually sent via the default route, determined by the lowest routing metric. However, I'm uncertain about whether MPTCP sends packets through both interfaces regardless of the default route. How is this achieved?

I attempted to discover how the default route is configured in practice. Unfortunately, I was unable to locate specific details on this matter.